# Leave Page event handle with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to manage logout event when user click on page leave so when come back on same page it redirect to login page.

On browser tab close i want to perform some session clear function.

Currently in my code issue happen that on page reload also this event triggered and session logout but i don't need to call this event on page refresh/reload i want only for browser close event handle message prompt with Leave/Cancel when user click on leave then i want to call logout event.

Below code i have perform :

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const handleBeforeUnload = (event: any) => {
      const customMessage = 'You are attempting to leave the agent screen without logging out. This may result in lost information. Are you sure you want to exit this page?';
      event.preventDefault();
      event.returnValue = customMessage;
    };
  
    const handleUnload = () => {
      // Clear data on page close
      reduxDispatch(onSelectCampaign(""));
      RemoveCookiesData();
      clearAllData(reduxDispatch);
    };
  
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    window.addEventListener('unload', handleUnload);
  
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
      window.removeEventListener('unload', handleUnload);
    };
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = true;
  };

  const handleUnload = () => {
    reduxDispatch(onSelectCampaign(""));
    RemoveCookiesData();
    clearAllData(reduxDispatch);
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
  window.addEventListener('unload', handleUnload);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    window.removeEventListener('unload', handleUnload);
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: I have try above code but it's not working that also clear session on reload page.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have different unload events between reloading a page or closing a tab. What you can do is using the `Session Storage`. This storage will be cleared, when the user closes the tab.

Set a key/value pair into the session storage all the time when the events `unload/beforeunload` get triggered.
Check this special key/value pair in your `useEffect` hook, when the component gets mounted the next time. In case the key/value pair is still available you know that the user just reloaded the page on the other hand if the key/value pair is empty you can be sure that the user opened your page in a new tab.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // please have a look into the session storage documentation how to implement it in a safe way
  const setReloadFlag = (isReloaded) => sessionStorage.setItem('reloaded', isReloaded)

  const handleBeforeUnload = (event) => {
    setReloadFlag('true');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = true;
  };

  const handleUnload = () => {
    setReloadFlag('true');
    reduxDispatch(onSelectCampaign(""));
    RemoveCookiesData();
    clearAllData(reduxDispatch);
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
  window.addEventListener('unload', handleUnload);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleBeforeUnload);
    window.removeEventListener('unload', handleUnload);
  };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem('reloaded') !== 'true'){
    // add your code for a cleanup/logout before your app loads again
  }

  setReloadFlag('false')
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I have try above code but during leave page that not perform clearsession event or when user click Ctrl+Shift+T that time user directly inside login without redirect on login page.

I want to make if leave direct from browser then any time direct try to open url that redirect to login page.

Comment: Thats right, like I said before the clean up will be made on the next page visit and not on page leave. This should not be a problem you just have to adjust your component, which is responsible to check if the user is logged in or not. Can you share the code of the responsible component?